# Multi-threads writing same thing to the same file?

Tags: java, synchronized

I alway thought concurrently threads writing to one same file needs synchronization.

What happend when multi-threads writing same thing to the same file without synchronization? I imagined the output file must be incomplete or corrupted.

```
public class Test 
{   
  public Runnable createLayoutRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("mov.mp4");

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("mov_co.mp4");
                //IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

                //synchronized ("lock"){
                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                //}

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is done"); 



            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    //Create Thread Pool for parallel layout
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9);

    //Run Tasks and wait for termination in the current thread
    Future<?> f1 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f2 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f3 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f4 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f5 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f6 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f7 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f8 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());
    Future<?> f9 = executor.submit(test.createLayoutRunnable());


    try {
        f1.get();
        f2.get();
        f3.get();
        f4.get();
        f5.get();
        f6.get();
        f7.get();
        f8.get();
        f9.get();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();

    System.out.println("all done");

}

}
```

Surprise! The output mov is good to play! 
How come? Please help!

Edit: Before all, I'm terribly sorry about the confusion. Yes the first-time code I posted was synchronised as opposed to what I said. I have commented it off now. This is because I was playing with the code and that's where I found whether it's synchronised or not doesn't matter and was wondering why.

Comment: Well of course it is, you are writing to the file in a synchronized block

Comment: But you are synchronizing. You're using a string as your lock, which is insane, but it's still synchronizing.

Comment: Is that luck that the string is the same instance in all threads? Becuase if its not the same instance hes not really synchronizing anything.

Comment: @kutschkem It's the same instance. (The string literal is interned)

Comment: @NathanHughes Sorry about the confusion. Yes it was synchronised but see my edit. And yes it's bad practice to use literal string as a lock, I just did it quick and dirty.

Comment: @kutschkem yes the synchronisation is on class level and it's on purpose.

Comment: I liked actually your idea of synch("lock"). The problem with it that you cannot use the same word always, since you may want different locks rather than one big. I am curious about other implications.

Comment: Another disadvantage of string literal is that java tools cannot find all references to show you the places where your lock is also used.

Answer (score 3):

In this *particular* case, you're writing identical content from an input file to identical locations in an output file. This is what's called an [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) operation, and it doesn't matter whether you synchronize or not.

If each thread wrote its own source file (and you eliminated synchronization), you'd see that either (1) one thread would win, or (2, more likely) you'd get interleaved (corrupted) content.

Comment: What? you have to write ABC. First thread writes AB, second AB then they finish writhing C and C. You get ABABCC in result. I think that idempotence is a professional word for looking serious and professional.

Comment: @Val - You would be correct if there was only one instance of the output stream, shared between threads. But that's not what's happening here: there's one instance *per thread*, and each instance will start writing at byte 0.

Comment: As for the use of the word "idempotence": like all "serious and professional" words, it carries a very specific meaning and is both quicker to say and less ambiguous than "all threads will do the same thing."

Comment: We see outputStream.write. One thread makes the first write. Another thread adds more data with another write. The spec of output stream says that you "add to the end" rather than overwrite. Idempotence, when second write goes over the first one instead of going to the end, is against java (and general concept of) stream. Intimidating people with it is inappropriate here, therefore.

Comment: @Val - I'm not sure what to say to you. Either (1) you don't see that a new stream is being opened for each thread, or (2) you don't understand how independent instances of a `FileOutputStream` work. Although, to be fair, the "[spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream)" for this behavior is implied rather than explicit, and may only be obvious to someone who is already familiar with the POSIX [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) call on which it's based.

Comment: Ok, may be you right. Might be java streams manage file pointer in duplication of the underlying file handler. But, I am not sure what POSIX has to do with java platform independence and Windows in particularly. Regarding the doc you have supplied, it seems that FileOutputStream is simple pointer to the system file descriptor. So that it does not seem to maintain a separate file pointer.

Comment: @Val - Much of the core Java library (especially IO) is based on POSIX. Much of Windows IO is also based on POSIX, or at least supports POSIX functionality. So that's a good place to look for additional information about behavior of Java library functions.

Comment: As for creatinga separate file pointer: yes, actually it does, as specified in "It shall create an open file description"; the spec does not say anything about reusing an existing file description, and in specs everything not permitted is prohibited. Also, while we're on the topic of vocabulary, "file pointer" has a specific definition that is different from "file descriptor."

Comment: I think of POSIX as a Unix file I/O interface. Windows has its own interface. As I point out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717397/multi-threads-writing-same-thing-to-the-same-file/16717936?noredirect=1#comment24071898_16718261, file handler management is quite different, despite of similar interface.

Comment: Do you mean that if java spec does not says that you cannot create a class called Mamma then it is prohibited? Why do you confuse the terms "file pointer" and "file descriptor", by quoting a spec says that opening a file description opens another file pointer and, immediately after that correct me by saying that that this is wrong?

Comment: If file description is not the same as file handler then it may easily happen that, accroding to spec, two file descriptors are created, which point to the same underlying file handler (file pointer). Right? So, you will get no file idempotence in this case. So, you have idempotence by luck here, not because it is defined to be so. So, the chance is primary, the idempotence is a consequence and things do not happen because of idempotence.

Comment: @Val - "Do you mean that if java spec does not says that you cannot create a class called Mamma then it is prohibited?" - you're creating a strawman here, because the Java spec explicitly permits you to create your own classes. A better example would be creating a class named "Momma!": [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) explicitly tells you what characters are allowed in an identifier. Implicitly, those that don't meet the specification are not allowed.

Comment: "Why do you confuse the terms "file pointer" and "file descriptor", by quoting a spec " - I don't. I mistakenly typed "file pointer" in response to your comment. You will not find the word "pointer" in the page that I linked to.

Comment: "I think of POSIX as a Unix file I/O interface" - that wasn't its intent. You can learn more at the X/Open site. As for Windows compliance: yes, there are differences, but at one point Windows was advertising itself as POSIX-compliant. You can Google for more information.

Comment: "If file description is not the same as file handler " - I have no idea what you're saying here. "File handler" has no defined meaning, and a POSIX "file pointer" holds a reference to a "file descriptor," not the other way around.

Comment: "File handler" is a basic Win32 term. You can Google for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, even if you took out the synchronisation, each thread is writing the same content to the same file. Because each thread is using a separate OutputStream (and InputStream) the threads do not interfere with each other's file position. Thus the output is a copy of the input file.

It's analogous to this:

```
public static int a;
public static int b;
public static int c;
```

With the threaded code being:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
```

Imagine you have two threads, A and B. The sequence of execution might run as follows, for example:

- A sets a = 1;
- A sets b = 2;
- B sets a = 1;
- A sets c = 3;
- B sets b = 2;
- B sets c = 3;

It doesn't matter how many threads run that sequence nor whether they are synchronised, once they are finished the contents of {a,b,c} will always be {1,2,3} (with some caveats that don't apply when writing to an external file). It's the same with your example copying a file - the contents of the output file are always the same; the exact sequence of execution in the threads doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreaded access does not mean that you will get garbage. It means that **result is inpredictable**. Some systems may just synchronize something themselves and result may seem like it is accessed under mutex.

Secondly, **your code is synchronized**, as opposed to what you say. Do you see that section sync("lock")? At first you say that it is not synchronized. Then, we look into the code and see that it is synchronized. Then we think that "lock", visible to the first thread is different from what another sees. But it is the same object because in java "static string" == "static string". So, the thread makes the full copy under lock. Then another comes and makes the full copy. Sure, the playback will be uninterrupted.

The only thing in file manipulation that goes outside synchronization is file open/close. (close?) Try in Linux. This may make a big difference there.

Comment: I'm using mac os. I assume it's very similar to Linux?

Comment: I am not sure. But we once debugged our multithreaded file access in windows, which worked when one thread deleted a file and another used it (or something like that) then no errors appeared in Windows (because it used two file handles or something) yet error was in Linux. So, manipulating file contents in critical section, while leaving file open/close/delete outside may lead different results, depending on OS.